# Accounts Tab(Visualforce Tab) is not visible

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, security

Accounts Tab(Visualforce Tab) is not visible for a user even after adding in the Customise apps. It is not visible for users having a specific Profile.

Checked with Read, create, edit, delete permission and also "Default on". But still cannot see.

In case, Accounts tab shows up sometimes, and when tried to open shows the following error:

**`*License required The Visualforce page zaapit_tb_AccountWL is part of the AppExchange package ZaapIT Tools and requires a license to use. For details, refer to No Access Permission Error.***`[image]

Comment: What License do your users in problem use?

Comment: Salesforce License

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you exactly what's wrong. You need to assign a package license to the user in order to view the tab. Go to the user's detail page, go down to Managed Packages, and click on Assign Licenses. From there, you can assign the appropriate license to activate the tab.